# nlog using the connectionStringName for database logging

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, logging, nlog

here is my nlog.config file. I have turned on the throwsException.

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  throwExceptions="true">
      <targets>   
        <target type="Database" name="databaseLog"
        dbProvider="sqlserver"   connectionstring="server=.\SQLExpress;database=Movie;integrated security=true">
            <commandText>
                INSERT INTO [Log] ([Description] , [Level] ) VALUES (@Description,  @Level )
            </commandText>
            <parameter name="@Description" layout="${message}"/> 
            <parameter name="@Level" layout="${level}"/>
        </target>

      </targets>

      <rules>
         <logger name="*" minLevel="Trace"  appendTo="databaseLog"/> 
      </rules>
</nlog>
```

This will work and *will insert records into the database*. However I would like to use connectionstringName and not retype the connectionstring. 
When I change the ***connectionstring*** to ***connectionstringname*** like this....

```
connectionstring="server=.\SQLExpress;database=Movie;integrated security=true"
```

to

```
connectionStringName="ApplicationConnectionString"
```

I get an error 
Expecting non-empty string for 'providerInvariantName' parameter

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add `System.Data.SqlClient` to attribute `ProviderName` in your connection string in web.config/app.config:

```
<add name="ApplicationConnectionString" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
connectionString="server=.\SQLExpress;database=Movie;integrated security=true;"/>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify where does this go nLog config or web.config? Thanks.