# NLog connectionStringName for Azure Worker Role csdef

Tags: app-config, nlog, azure-worker-roles

I'm trying to use [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) with Azure SQL as log DB in order to trace processes in Azure Worker Role.

It works when I set *connectionString* in NLog.config as below.

```
<target name="database"
    connectionString=Server=tcp:some.database.windows.net,1433...`
    ...
/>
```

But I'd like to use `connectionStringName` given from `ServiceConfiguration.csdef` which overridden result of `App.Config`.

App.Config defines connection string as below,

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="LogConnectionString" value="Server=tcp:some.database.windows.net,1433;..." />
</appSettings>
```

And, `ServiceConfiguration.csdef` defines its value to Dev/Test/Live separately.

The NLog throws exception during initialization as below.

> ---> NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Connection string 'LogConnectionString' is not declared in  section.

Note that, [Adding providerName](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8823614/361100) in `App.Config` did not help. It seems that *providerName* property does not propagate to csdef configuration.

Can I achieve this *without* SlowCheetah config transform?

Comment: Is this also the case with NLog 4.3? There are some changes regarding the _providerName_ in NLog 4.3

Comment: @Julian // yes. I did it with latest version. I changed/omitted `providerName` but nothing happened well.

Comment: I think NLog this will only work if NLog does know how to read csdef files. I think we can add that easily if we know how to do that in C#. If you like, create a feature request: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/new

Comment: This could be also helpful: https://maximelabelle.wordpress.com/2015/01/16/integrating-nlog-with-azure-cloud-service-diagnostics/